# Layout not working either programmatically nor the xml

Tags: java, android

I created a app and want to add buttons programmatically. My buttons appear correclty but my button with id 'add_warranty disappears.

My code of activity.xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_warrantys"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/show_warratys"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_warranty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
        android:text="@string/add_button"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And my code to create buttons from a list and create the buttons one at the time:

```
List<Warranty> warrantys = db.getAllContacts();
    for (Warranty cn : warrantys) {
        String ID = Integer.toString(cn.getID());
        String buttonName = ID + "_" + cn.getName();
        String buttonText = "Name: " + cn.getName() + '\n' + " Bought on: " + cn.getStartDate() + '\n' + " Warranty stops on: " + cn.getEndDate();

        Button buttons = new Button(this);
        buttons.setTag(buttonName);
        buttons.setText(buttonText);
        buttons.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        buttonViewWarrantys.addView(buttons);

        String log = "Id: " + cn.getID() + " ,Name: " + cn.getName() + " ,Startdate: " + cn.getStartDate() + " ,EndDate: " + cn.getEndDate() + " ,Path: " + cn.getImgFilePath();
        System.out.println(log);
    }
```

This is what the layout looks like on the screen of the smartphone:

Picture of layout on the smartphone

[image]

Comment: Change ScrollView height to wrap_content

Comment: Thanks! But after this everything shows up in the middle.

Comment: Also change height of parent LinearLayout to wrap_content

Comment: So you do not want the `add_warranty` button to scroll?

Comment: Thanks again! Now my button is on the top and I want it at the bottom :)

Comment: Yes I don't want it to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your ScrollView layout_height attribute value.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/show_warratys"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the button has no space in your screen since scrollview is taking entire space due to its match_parent height attribute

Make your scrollview height attribute to 'wrap_content'

And to get that at the bottom use  layout_gravity attribute to 'bottom'

Answer (score 0):

as no space to show button , change the layout scrollview to stretch in whole rest of parent view

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/list_warrantys"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/show_warratys"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/add_warranty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
    android:text="@string/add_button"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
```